# MySQL составной запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

как правильно сделать запрос такого типа:

```
UPDATE in_main 
SET SelectionDescription='$SelectionDescription', 
    id = ('SELECT MAX('id') FROM `in_main`'+1) 
WHERE DocumentNumber='$DocumentNumber'
```

А именно меня интересует строчка

```
 id=('SELECT MAX('id') FROM `in_main`'+1)
```

То есть мне нужно изменить id записи на последний id+1.

P.S. поле id автоинкремент, я бы использовал mysqli_insert_id, но оно работает, только если insert был использован в текущем подключении.

Comment: Обновление поля-автоинкремента чревато боком. Заведите отдельное поле под такую нумерацию, а автоинкремент не трогайте.

Comment: Чего вы пытаетесь достичь таким запросом? Может вам нужно просто добавить в таблицу поле "последнее обновление записи"?

Comment: @Akina а почему может выйти боком, просто для саморазвития=)

Comment: См. [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html), от слов *Modifying AUTO_INCREMENT column values in the middle of a sequence of INSERT statements*.

Comment: Непосредственно по теме вопроса: В MySQL все, что в одинарных кавычках - это просто строка и `'SELECT .... 1'` представляет собой обычный текст, а не подзапрос. Подзапрос следовало бы заключать в скобки